All t-wise products of elements in a set
Let $G$ be an abelian group, and $S \subset G$ a set of size $|S| \geq t$. Let $T_S$ be the set of all products of $t$ distinct elements of $S$, i.e., $T_S = \{ x \mid x = \prod_{s \in S'} s, S' \subset S, |S'|=t\}$. Some questions one might ask:

For a given $t' \geq t$, what sets $S$ of size $t'$ make $T_S$ largest/smallest?
For a given set $G' \subseteq G$, what is the smallest $S$ such that $G' \subseteq T_S$?
For a given group $G$, what is the smallest $t'$ such that every set $S$ of size $t'$ has $T_S=G$?

Such questions seem vaguely related to questions about sumsets and the like from additive combinatorics, but I have been unable to find any references. I am not looking for answers to the above questions, but can anyone give me pointers or the right search terms to look for? If it helps, I am most interested in the case where $G$ is the nonzero integers modulo a prime, i.e., the multiplicative group of a prime field.

What is $t'$ in the first bullet?

edited to clarify (though the questions are just meant to be suggestive, my real question is about what names this might have been studied as).

What does $\prod_{s \in S'} s$ mean when $G$ is not abelian?

clarified that $G$ is abelian
